# Save a Excel 2010 file, when another user has opened it

Tags: java

we have a excel file on our server, that contains a calendar for some people. So most time the excel file is opened by someone. Is there a way with java, that I can save the current state of the file and save it to another folder?

I took a look into apache.poi and windows shadow copy, but I can not see a way with java.

Thank you.

Comment: Em.. Apache POI is actually java library for excel manipulations... (Java API for Microsoft Documents). How you "can not see a way with java" is not clear.

Comment: If it is a contain calendar data maybe you should use google calendars(or another calendaring program) and then having the calendar shared with 1000+ people in no problem at all.  There is even a google calendar API if you want to interact with it programmatically.  Also you can share it on cell phones with no additional effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the second person to open the file, Excel usually asks if you want to open a copy or wait until the file is available. If you open a copy, you get the version on the drive (it may not have the latest updates) where you can save anywhere.